# Why does wrapping navbar links in a container mess up this layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm having two problems with my responsive navbar that I can't get my head around. If I wrap everything within the "nav-bar" class in a container, and set the max width to 1170px, then my flexbox rules go out of the window and it changes the layout. I want to do this so my logo and links keep the appropiate boarder inline with the boarder of the whole page, while keeping the black background to the edge of the page.

Here is a screenshot of the navbar I'm trying to replicate. [image] The links and logo are sat within a container within the navbar.

My second problem is that if I set the "nav-bar to have a minimum height of 12 vh (so my navbar can use the logo.png that I have. The responsive drop down menu doesn't respect this minimum height. On the mobile few the logo and links are not aligned center and then toggling the menu doesn't start from the bottom of the navbar. I've attached screenshots.

The first screen shot shows the minimum height of 12vh on desktop view and the next 2 screen shots show what happens on mobile view

[image]

This screenshot shows how the logo and hamburger menu is not center in mobile view 
[image]

This last screen shot shows how the responsive menu doesn't start from the bottom of the navbar which is set to have a min height of 12vh
[image]

How do I fix these issues?

Thanks

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.brand-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 12vh on mobile will be different then desktop because it takes a specific height based on the viewport, set a fixed height to fix that issue

Comment: and the mobile menu dropdown seems to work fine in the code snipped provided, is there any difference on screen width or browser maybe? i am using chrome version 83.0

Comment: The 12vh works on mobile but the logo and hamburger are not centered as can been seen in the screenshot. Then when I click on the hamburger, the links don't start from the bottom of the navbar, they start from the bottom of the logo and hamburger. Look at the screenshots. I'm trying to adapt the code that I've posted to do what I've stated.